# Efficient way to retrieve documents from MongoDB using ids in a result set array field

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

My MongoDB version is 3.4. I have documents similar to these:

```
{
 id: 1,
 refs: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
},

{
 id: 3,
 refs: [2, 5, 8]
}
```

Integers in refs array indicate other documents' ids in the same collection. What I want to achieve is to retrieve all documents in all refs combined in a result set. Suppose my imaginary query matches documents with ids 1 and 3 above, I am trying to get all the documents with 1's refs + 3's refs (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8)

I used $unwind + $lookup to first deconstruct refs array to individual documents and then look up in the same collection to retrieve entire documents, but I think this performs a separate query for each id in refs.

Is there a more efficient method?

Comment: No, it's only 2 queries - first to get ids, the second is $lookup to fetch documents by selected ids. And no, there is no better way to do that. You don't need to unwind tho, $lookup accepts an array as a localField.

Comment: You might consider graphLookup https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/#-graphlookup--aggregation-

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a way of querying match {id:1} and {id:3} and combining them in a single line. But you can add a document that references 1 and 3 id's like below:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("60dd201bdb16e85753c4eef0"),
        "id" : 1,
        "refs" : [
                2,
                3,
                4,
                5,
                6
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("60dd201bdb16e85753c4eef1"),
        "id" : 3,
        "refs" : [
                2,
                5,
                8
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("60dd27acdb16e85753c4eef2"),
        "id" : 10,
        "refs" : [
                1,
                3
        ]
}
```

And then you can use match aggregate like {$match: {id: 10}} This makes a join with [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) and brings what you want in a single line.

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {$match: {id: 10}},
    {$lookup: {
        from: "test",
        localField: "refs",
        foreignField: "id",
        as: "result"
    }},
    {$set: {result: {$reduce: {
        input: "$result.refs",
        initialValue: [],
        in: {$setUnion: ["$$value", "$$this"]},
    }}}}
]);
```

The result is:

{ "_id" : ObjectId("60dd27acdb16e85753c4eef2"), "id" : 10, "refs" : [ 1, 3 ], `"result" : [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8 ] }`

We used at first pipeline stage [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) and thus made a left join on same collection. And then used [$setUnion](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/) opearator in a [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) aggregate function.

Not: We didn't use [$concatArrays](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/) for duplicate items.